# How to use Spring's "user-by-username-query" clause in a Java class?

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring security to validate user login.

User credentials are stored in database.

Here is the related section from my "**appContext-security.xml**" file.

This code works - but my problem is that I am using **raw SQL query** for "***user-by-username-query***"  and "***authorities-by-username-query***' tags.
Thus if I have to support multiple databases and if the Sql syntax varies, then I have a problem.

So can I put those queries in some form of a Java class? so that I can change the SQL syntax in that java class easily and make these SQLs **DB dependent**?

```
<authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="jndiDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select name, password, enabled from USER where user_status&lt;&gt;0 and name=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select m.name,p.name from USER m, ROLE p where m.name=? and m.application_role=p.id"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:/appManaged"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare `JdbcDaoImpl` as a bean manually instead of using `<jdbc-user-service>`:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref = "jdbcUserService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id = "jdbcUserService" 
    class = "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name = "dataSource" ref = "jndiDataSource" />
    <beans:property name = "usersByUsernameQuery" 
         value = "select name, password, enabled from USER where user_status&lt;&gt;0 and name=?"
" />
    ...
</beans:bean>
```

Then you can do whatever you want, for example, declare it to be obtained from a factory that sets appropriate queries, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I can still see that the SQL is part of XML definition. How should I provide my own implementation of JdbcDaoImpl so that I can override its setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery() and setUsersByUsernameQuery() apis?

Comment: I got it. I have introduced my own DaoImpl class extending from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl and then override the "public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)" api appropriately. Now I have more control. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.